# How to access each string from lists of tuple of strings and consolidate it?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have three list like

```
course=[("MA101","Calculus"),("PH101","Mechanics"),("HU101","English")]

grade= [("UGM2018001", "MA101", "AB"), ("UGP2018132", "PH101", "B"), ("UGM2018001", "PH101", "B")]

student= [("UGM2018001","Rohit Grewal"),("UGP2018132","Neha Talwar")]
```

and I want to print the output like

```
r=[('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal', [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]), ('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar', [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')])]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What step are you getting stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be fancier `zip` options, but here is how you can do it with standard loops. The only thing to pay attention to is how to append a list to a tuple, i.e. using `myTuple+(myList,)` or `myTuple+tuple([myList])`, instead of `myTuple+tuple(myList)` or `myTuple+tuple(myList)`.

```
course=[("MA101","Calculus"),("PH101","Mechanics"),("HU101","English")]

grade= [("UGM2018001", "MA101", "AB"), ("UGP2018132", "PH101", "B"), ("UGM2018001", "PH101", "B")]

student= [("UGM2018001","Rohit Grewal"),("UGP2018132","Neha Talwar")]

final = []
for s in student:
    temp = []
    for g in grade:
        for c in course:
            if s[0] in g and g[1] in c:
                t = c+(g[2],)
                temp.append(t)
    final.append(s + (temp,))
print final
```

Result:

```
[('UGM2018001', 'Rohit Grewal', [('MA101', 'Calculus', 'AB'), ('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')]), ('UGP2018132', 'Neha Talwar', [('PH101', 'Mechanics', 'B')])]
```